# Issues with recursive bool function

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, binary, boolean

```
bool search(double x, TreeNode *t)
{
    if (t->value == x)
        return true;
    else if (x < t->value)
        search(x, t->left);
    else if (x > t->value)
        search(x, t->right);
    return false;

bool search(double num)
{
    TreeNode *ptr = root;
    return search(num, ptr);
}
```

The search function with 2 arguments is a private member function of a binary tree class that uses recursion to search for a value.  The other search function is called to call the recursive function.  This code does not work.  I have displayed the value of the recursive function and it does not return 0 or 1.  I have no idea why.  Also, if I send in a value that is not in the tree, the program crashes so I get no errors to help me.

Comment: `search(x, t->left);` - don't you mean `return search(x, t->left);`?

Comment: first of all function return bool, which is true value and not 1/0, there is no nullptr check, there is no return on the recursion call.

Comment: A `double` and a `==` do not mix. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: You should check that root is not nullptr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursion never stops if you don't find an element.
If it's found in the root, you return `true`.
If it's found somewhere else, you return `false`.

You need to

1. Handle the empty tree, and
2. Return something meaningful when recursing.

Like

```
bool search(double x, const TreeNode *t)
{
    if (t == nullptr)
        return false;
    else if (t->value == x)
        return true;
    else if (x < t->value)
        return search(x, t->left);
    else
        return search(x, t->right);
}
```

or

```
bool search(double x, const TreeNode *t)
{
    return t != nullptr
          && (  t->value == x
            || (t->value < x && search(x, t->left))
            || (t->value > x && search(x, t->right)));
}
```

Comment: This works.  Thank you very much.  I didn't even think to use return when calling recursion.